# Fix a container overflow issue in the footer

Tags: html, css, shopify

on [this](http://gioventu-new-york.myshopify.com/pages/contact) page, i'm trying to get the footer (the newsletter signup form) to fall to the bottom of the page.

but #container is somehow bigger than the body and it's messing everything up. any ideas?

here is an image of the issue. the blue is the end of the  tag. https://i.stack.imgur.com/spg9a.png

```
body#page {
background-color: white;
background-image: none;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

container {
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is.  Could be a browser issue.  Would you mind taking a screen shot and indicated the problem visually?

Comment: @CaseyRule sure here is the issue (added more info above also) http://i.imgur.com/1Ww3C6R.png (updated image with more context)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your div.container is set to height:100%; It would be okay if it started at the top of the page, but it is offset by your header. You need to do following:

First of all, use border-box to keep all paddings within your elements' dimensions.

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Now you need to create a wrapper for your content and put your footer right below it

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="drawer">...</div>
    <div class="container">...</div>
</div>
<footer>...</footer>
```

And css:

```css
.wrapper{
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 padding-bottom:50px; /* reserving bottom space for footer */ }

.container{ 
 display: inline-block; /* don't force it to 100%, just make it flexible  */
 float:left; /* using float will spare you from extra white-space bug occuring in pages with elements having display:inline-block property */
 clear:both;
 width: 100%;  }

footer { 
 width: 100%;
 float:left;
 clear: both;
 height:50px;
 margin-top:-50px; /*moving it into the padded bottom space of wrapper*/ }
```

There you go. Now your footer will stick to your bottom of the page unless your content is larger than 100% of the screens height. Then it will just go down respectively.

Comment: thank you very much. this all makes sense. and i got rid of the overflow. but the positioning of the container is still off. any ideas? http://gioventu-new-york.myshopify.com/

Comment: Sorry, my bad. The footer is supposed to go outside of the wrapper. I fixed the html snippet already - have a look. Let me know if it works.